# How to implement TYPE_C VBUS status LED?

Tags: led, current

On my custom PCB I have a type-C connector with PD option.

I want a visual indication on my board when someone has plugged a cable in. I was thinking of connecting an LED to the VBUS pins in the type-C connector. The problem is that the VBUS is unknown (it can be 5, 9, 15 or 20 V).

Usually I can adjust the current flowing through the LED with a resistor and a simple calculation. I know from previous experience that the particular LED I am using (597-5311-407F) ([datasheet](https://www.mouser.co.uk/datasheet/2/109/smt_selector_guide-1163647.pdf)) lights up nicely with 33 mA of current (I am not sure what the allowed current boundaries are).

So if VBUS is 5 V then a 150 Ω resistor would be fine. The problem is that if VBUS is at the maximum 20 V, there will be 133.33 mA through the LED and I think that is too much.

1. What is the easiest way to implement such a visual LED circuit on the VBUS type-C line??
2. Will the circuit below work with the maximum 20 V without damaging the LED?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foN9WP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Is there another voltage rail within the device which runs at a constant voltage? Also, 33 mA is quite a lot for a small LED - have you tried it running at maybe 5 mA or 10 mA?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I have a constant 3.3v rail in my board (generated from vbus ldo),and i have connected a led to it ,but that will not tell me if the LDO itself is not mounted well . i was searching for an option to see a visual indication of the VBUS itself . Yea 33mA is probably high , but in the data sheet i can't find the maximum forward current of this specific led , they have only test current(mA) parameter , and it is 20mA for this LED , but from experience with this led i know 33mA won't demage it .

Comment: My suggestion was going to be to use a 3.3 V LDO regulator, with a suitable allowed input voltage range, and a 47 Ω resistor in series with the LED. But if you want to check that the existing LDO regulator is working, maybe that wouldn't be such a good idea.

Comment: Maybe as a workaround i will add another 3 leds ,and another 4 comperators , i will set the voltage dividers as such that if i have above 17V **all led** will light indicating that (20v is on) , if 13v (then **3 led will light on** indicating that 9v is on ) , and so on ...  i Have found an example circuit  [Circuit example her](https://imgur.com/gallery/iSh9eDL) , my question now is as follows , is the red circle i have marked is mandatory? or you dont have to add the mosfet and 2 extra resistors ? can some one explain why they have added the mosfet and 2 resistors ?